# Ошибка в хранимой процедуре MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Необходимо написать хранимую процедуру, которая увеличивает комиссионные у тех продавцов, сумма продаж которых превышает среднюю сумму продаж всей компании. В написанной мной процедуре отображается ошибка (Не удалось привязать составной идентификатор "a.sum_zakaz".)
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, что является причиной данной ошибки?
Скрипт:

```
create procedure comis_plus
@value decimal
as
update prodavec 
set comis_prod=comis_prod+@value
where avg(a.sum_zakaz)<(select sum(a.sum_zakaz)
                        from zakaz a, prodavec b
                        where a.id_prod=b.id_prod)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так сделайте, у вас обновляется продавец но нет условий на фильтрацию с этой таблицей

```
create procedure comis_plus
@value decimal
@avgsum decimal
as
-- вычислите среднюю сумму продаж всей компании
SELECT @avgsum = avg(sum_zakaz) FROM zakaz

-- далее имея значение можно не извращяться запросами

update zakaz 
set comis_prod=zakaz.comis_prod+@value
where zakaz.id_prod in (select a.id_prod
                        from zakaz a, prodavec b
                        where a.id_prod=b.id_prod
                        GROUP BY a.id_prod
                        having @avgsum < sum(a.sum_zakaz)                      
                        )
```

UPD.Изменил процедуру добавил коментариев

Comment: Вместо Where поставить having?

Comment: Снова ошибка...Статистическое выражение не может использоваться в предложении WHERE, если оно не содержится во вложенном запросе предложения HAVING

Comment: Обновил ответ немного :)

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!! )

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется - я не проверял - что поменять надо вот что:

```
    where avg(zakaz.sum_zakaz)<(select sum(a.sum_zakaz)
                            from zakaz a, prodavec b
                            where a.id_prod=b.id_prod)
```

То есть, синоним a для zakaz относится только к выражению в скобках

Comment: Аналогичная ситуация (

Comment: ну. a.sum_zakaz осталось только в одном месте. Может, вообще избавиться от синонимов?

Comment: Сейчас пишет (Недопустимое имя столбца "sum_zakaz".)

Comment: Так там и заказов нет подключенных к продавцам

Comment: Update prodavec...from prodavec inner join zakaz ... Where zakaz.....